# Quadrilaterals in CSS

Tags: css

is there a way to draw a quadrilateral in CSS, without using the border properties? I saw this method to draw [quadrilaterals here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/):

Here is a sample code using borders:

```
.bluequad {
    border-bottom: 18px solid #00b8af;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

But I do not want to tweak the borders. I need a way to make quadrilaterals without using border properties. How can that be done?

Comment: From the example link that you have given, you can manipulate the properties of Trapezoid or Parallelogram to get quadrilateral.

Comment: The only way to get anything close to this is 3D transformations. As far as my burned-out brain can figure out right now, you should be able to get any convex quadrilateral just by transforming a square or rectangle in 3D space.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the exact shape you're looking for?  A quadrilateral is any shape with 4 sides.  Parallelogram?  Trapezoid?  Diamond?  Kite?  Rhombus?  None of the above?

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd rather do this with HTML+CSS than with SVG?

Comment: Convex or concave? Could some of them be a bowtie shape or will the edges never intersect? Solid filled-in shape, outlined shape not filled in, or solid filled-in shape with outline? Are these static shapes that never change, or do you need to be able to render an arbitrary quadrilateral with dynamic or random vertices?

Comment: You can use CSS Gradients and background-image

Comment: If you don't want to use border...I would suggest you use SVG!

Answer (score 2):

For some basic quads you can use different combinations of skews:

```
transform: skewX(20deg) skewY(20deg)
```